# Find gain of this common-gate

Tags: mosfet, feedback, gain, closed-loop, common-gate

I have a large circuit involving feedback as follows

[image]

[image]

I am trying to find the closed-loop gain of this. Before I can do that, I need to find the open-loop gain. Thus, removing the feedback loop, M2 becomes useless and I am left with a common-gate stage below

[image]

Now, I need to find the gain of this circuit Vout/Iin and I make the following small-signal model
[image]

**I can't seem to get Vout/Iin from this. Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gain will be [Rd || (R1 + R2) || outputSlopeOfDrain] * deltaIin.

To compute the outputSlopeOfDrain, you need the lambda effect in the FET model.